# Unexpected empty strings within Python strings

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Observe the following interactive session:

```
In [1]: s = 'emptiness'

In [2]: s.replace('', '*')
Out[2]: '*e*m*p*t*i*n*e*s*s*'

In [3]: s.count('')
Out[3]: 10
```

I discovered this today, and it is a little confusing and surprising for me.

I love learning things like this about Python, but it seems like this could lead to some pretty confusing gotchas. For example, if the empty string was passed in as a variable, and just *happened* to be an empty string, you could end up with some surprising consequences. The behavior also seems a little inconsistent, because based on the interactive session above, I would think that the following would produce a list of all the characters in the string (similar to the JavaScript behavior). Instead, you get an error:

```
In [4]: s.split('')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c31bd2432bc1> in <module>()
----> 1 s.split('')

ValueError: empty separator
```

Also, this leads to some seemingly contradictory behavior with `str.endswith()` and `str.startswith()`:

```
In [5]: s.endswith('')
Out[5]: True

In [6]: s.endswith('s')
Out[6]: True

In [7]: s.startswith('')
Out[7]: True

In [8]: s.startswith('e')
Out[8]: True
```

Experimenting with various [string methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods), you can find more similarly strange examples.

My question is *why* does the empty string behave this way? Or is this the result of how the `str` methods are handling empty strings? If anyone has any insights, or can point me in the direction of an explanation/description of this behavior, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 7):

Python strings follow the principle that an empty string is a subset of every other string. Furthermore, python strings are also concatenations of byte strings, implying that a string consists of bytes sandwiched between empty strings. You can see that by the following examples:

```
>>>'a'.count('')
2
>>>'aa'.count('')
3
>>>'string'.count('')
7
```

So `'a'` must be `''+'a'+''`, and `'aa'` must be `''+'a'+''+'a'+''`.

When you check `'a'.startswith('')`, it sees that the string 'a' technically starts with an empty string. Same for `'a'.endswith('')`. However when you check `'a'.startswith('a')`, it ignores the empty string and looks at the first byte.